# derivate a function in 1

Tags: integration, functions, derivatives

how are you? They ask me to derive the function in $1$, I have already done all the possible accounts and it gives me (depending on the account I do) $1$ or that it does not exist.
The functions is
$f:\left(0;+\infty\right)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\ln x}{1-e^{x-1}}&x\ne 1\\
-1 & x=1\\
\end{cases}
$$
So $f'(1)$ is....
i think that this function is not possible to derivative in $1$ , but it's strange because some times give me $1$.... I don't where start , if its beater Hlopital or what..
thanks

Comment: you have to check if $f$ has a derivative in $1$. Compute the left derivative of $f$ and the right derivative in $x=1$ and check if those values are the same

Comment: but i don't have > or < ... there are just = and ≠ ... maybe you mean , calculate the limit in 1 , and check if the limit 1 by left it's the same ?

Comment: left derivatife of $f$ in $x=1$ is cumputed as follows: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1^{-}}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a computation using Taylor series.
The derivative at $x = 1$ (if it exists) is the limit
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(1 + h) - f(1)}{h} &= 
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac 1h \left[\frac{\ln(1 + h)}{1 - e^{h}} + 1\right]
\\ & = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\ln(1 + h) -(e^{h}-1)}{h(1 - e^{h})}
\\ & = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{\ln(1 + h)}{h} -\frac{e^{h}-1}{h}}{1 - e^{h}}
\\ & = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1 - \frac 12 h + o(h) -(1 + \frac 12 h + o(h))}{-h+o(h)}
\\ & = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-h + o(h)}{-h+o(h)} = 1.
\end{align}
$$
So, the derivative at $x = 1$ exists and $f'(1) = 1$.

Comment: i did like this ... but some times gime that the derivative dosen't exist

Comment: @carlos If you could show the work you did that leads to the conclusion that the derivative does not exist, perhaps we can see what is wrong with that approach

Comment: hahhahaha i know what i did wrong .... i wrote ln(1+h) +1 / 1- e^h ....... and is ln(1+h) / 1- e^h +1  i dont know why i wrote this +1 in the numerator ... i need a break hahaha  . thanksssss BENN